# Limit as $x$ approaches $0$ for a function.

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Unfortunately this question does not make the slightest sense to me. I know how to find limits but this is confusing. Any help will be appreciated...

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^m)}{(\sin x)^p}$$

where $m$ and $p$ are positive integers. (Hint: the answer will depend on
$m$ and $p$.)

How will I find that? Thanks!

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone will provide a hint or a complete answer that will be based on what you know.

Comment: Okay so thanks to the guys who replied below I see that if I try to separate the function into three parts I will have sin(x^m)/x^m , x^p/sin(x^p) , and X^(m-p) and I already know that if I distribute the limit to the first two parts, I'll get 1 for both... What I dont understand is the the three cases for x^(m-p). How will I show the limit as x approaches 0 based on the integers and whether they are greater than, less than, or equal to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^m)}{(\sin{x})^p}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^m)x^p x ^m}{x^p x^m(\sin{x})^p}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x^m)}{x ^m}\cdot\dfrac{x^p}{(\sin{x})^p}\cdot\dfrac{x^m}{x^p}\right)$$

Comment: I don't understand how you managed to get from eq 1 to eq 2...

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin(x^m)}{(\sin{x})^p}=\dfrac{\sin(x^m)x^p x ^m}{x^p x^m(\sin{x})^p}=\dfrac{\sin(x^m)}{x ^m}\cdot\dfrac{x^p}{(\sin{x})^p}\cdot\dfrac{x^m}{x^p}$

Comment: But why did you do that? Why divide the function with x^m and x^p?

Comment: In order to use that $\dfrac{\sin(x^m)}{x ^m}\underset{x\to{0}}\rightarrow{1}$ and $\dfrac{x^p}{(\sin{x})^p}\underset{x\to{0}}\rightarrow{1}$

Comment: I understand now. Thanks! But what about the lim as x approaches 0 for x^(m-p). Should I present three possible cases as my answer depending on the m and p integers?

Comment: Yes, since limit behaviour depends on relation between $m$ and $p.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{\sin(x^m)}{(\sin x)^p}\sim \frac{x^m}{x^p}, \quad x \to 0.$$
Consider the cases $m=p$, $m>p$ and $m<p$.

Answer (score 2):

The function is equal to
$$
x^{m-p}\cdot\frac{\sin(x^m)}{x^m} \cdot \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^p.
$$

For the first fraction, note that $u=x^m$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$ so you've got
$$
\lim_{u\to0} \frac{\sin u}{u}.
$$
The second one involves the limit of the reciprocal of the same function.

The first factor $x^{m-p}$ must be dealt with separately.

Comment: Since m and p are positive integers, m-p will also be positive? Also I can see that the limit as u approaches 0 for sinu/u is equal to 1 but what about the third part?

Comment: $m-p$ is positive if $m>p$, and in that case $x^{m-p}\to0$.  If $m<p$ then $m-p$ is negative, so $x^{m-p}\to\pm\infty$.  If $m=p$ then $x^{m-p}=x^0=1$.

Comment: I understand how the integers work but how will use this information to tackle the question?

Comment: You have two fractions each approaching $1$ as $x\to 0$.  So the only remaining question is what is $\lim\limits_{x\to0} x^{m-p}\,{}$?