# Unable to proceed with this limit

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Find the limit $$\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{\sin(\alpha ^n)}{(\sin\alpha)^m}$$ (m and n are positive integers)

What I've tried so far-
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha ^n)}{\alpha^n}\frac{\alpha^n}{\frac{(\sin\alpha)^m\alpha^m}{\alpha^m}}$$

$$\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{\alpha^n}{\alpha^m}$$

Comment: Consider the three cases (1) $m<n$, (2) $m=n$, and (3) $m>n$. What happens in each case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit as $x$ approaches $0$ for a function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515952/limit-as-x-approaches-0-for-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the equivalence $$\sin (X)\sim X \;\;(X\to 0) $$

to get your limit as

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}f (\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\alpha^{n-m} $$

thus

If $n>m $, it is $0^{n-m}=0$.

if $n=m $, it is $1$.

if $n <m $,  then

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+}f (\alpha)=+\infty $$
$\lim_{\alpha \to 0^-}f (\alpha)=+\infty$ if $m-n $ is even

and

$\lim_{\alpha \to 0^-}f (\alpha)=-\infty $ if $m-n $ is odd.

Comment: why $-\infty$ when m-n is odd

Comment: @Abhishekstudent  cause it is $1/0^-$ which is $-\infty $.

Comment: (+1) You need not to say "hint when $n \ge 0$" since it is already mentioned that $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Also, you should write $\approx$ instead of $\sim$ as it will be more accurate.